# Too Much Happening with a Single Button Press in Unity (Multiple Bullets Cloning with Mouseclick)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am completely new to Unity 5 and have a problem when shooting a gun using the code I got in a tutorial. Here is my code:

```
static var ammo = 30;

var key : String = "mouse 0";

var speed : float = 100;

static var maxAmmo = 30;

var bullet : Rigidbody;

var dmg : float = 20;


function Update ()
{  
     if(Input.GetKeyDown(key)){

        if(ammo > 0){

            Shoot();
         }
     }
}

function Shoot() {
    var bullet1 : Rigidbody = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    bullet1.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
    ammo --;
}

function OnGUI(){
    GUI.Label(Rect(10,10,500,500), ""+ammo);
}

function OnTriggerEnter(hit:Collider){
     if(hit.tag == "Enemy"){
        hit.transform.SendMessage("Damage",dmg);
     }
 }
```

When I run this code, the clones of the bullets appear in multiples (Even as much as 8 bullets appear pretty much instantly), to illustrate:

*First click -> bullet(clone)*

*Next Click -> bullet(clone), bullet(clone)(clone)*

*Next click -> bullet(clone), bullet(clone)(clone), bullet(clone)(clone)(clone)*

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: To clarify, is your desire to fire multiple shots with a mouse click, but at a lower rate, or to only fire a single bullet with each mouse click?

Comment: Are you saying that on the first click you get one bullet, the second click you get two bullets, etc.?

Comment: I want just one shot per click.

Comment: userr3071, i get 1 bullet, then 2, then 4, then 8, then 16, then 32 etc. Wierd

Answer (score 0):

hmm looks like it should work, but i have never heard of "mouse 0" as a keycode.

try this

```
static var ammo = 30;

var mouse : int = 0;

var speed : float = 100;

static var maxAmmo = 30;

var bullet : Rigidbody;

var dmg : float = 20;


function Update ()
{  
     if(Input.GetMousebuttonDown(mouse) && ammo > 0)
         Shoot();
}

function Shoot() {
    var bullet1 : Rigidbody = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    bullet1.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
    ammo --;
}

function OnGUI(){
    GUI.Label(Rect(10,10,500,500), ""+ammo);
}

function OnTriggerEnter(hit:Collider){
     if(hit.tag == "Enemy"){
        hit.transform.SendMessage("Damage",dmg);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, nice code but the amount of bullets shooting doubles, from 1,2,4,8,16 etc. Hate it. Maybe its not the code?

Comment: I want just one shot every time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is that you are not 'waiting' before execute the next shoot.
The Update function will be called several times on each second.

So, you can shoot, raise a flag (iMShooting = true;) then, using a coroutine unlock the flag after X secs.
And also, add your flag iMShooting to your update function.

```
var iMShooting : boolean = false;

function Update ()
{  
   if(Input.GetKeyDown(key) && ! iMShooting){

      if(ammo > 0){

        Shoot();
      }
   }
}
```

and

```
function Shoot() {
    iMShooting = true;
    var bullet1 : Rigidbody = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    bullet1.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
    ammo --;
    StartCoroutine( shootingDone() ); 

}
```

Your coroutine should be something like:

```
function shootingDone()
{
    var waitTime : float = 0.5f;
    yield WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
    iMShooting = false;
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. [According to the docs, `GetKeyDown`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) is only active for the frame the key has been pressed.

Comment: Oh, you are right! On one hand the flag will avoid extra shoots but in another hand is not the right answer.

Comment: the ammo goes 29, 27, 23, 15, 0

Comment: The point is `iMShooting` will never avoid extra shoots, because intrinsically `getKeyDown` will only fire one time on a single frame

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help but i realized the duplicates of the bullets spawn from the bullets themselves, and i realized i put the shoot script onto the bullets so the bullets act as guns themselves. I have removed the script and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!